# Spring MVC form action not mapping to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a very simple form with a username and password entry and I simply want to redirect the form to be handled by the LoginController. For some reason the controller is never getting control of the form

Here is my form html code

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form:form method="post" action="login">
        <div><label for="username">Username:</label> </div>
        <div> <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></div>
        <div><label for="password">Password:</label></div>
        <div><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    </form:form>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    public LoginController() {
        //Initialize controller properties here or 
        //in the Web Application Context

        //setCommandClass(MyCommand.class);
        //setCommandName("MyCommandName");
        //setSuccessView("successView");
        //setFormView("formView");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login()
    {
        System.out.println("entered");
        return "myAccount";
    }
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="login">loginController</prop>
            </props>

        </property>
    </bean>

<bean name="loginController" class="net.fluidinnovations.issuetracking.controllers.LoginController"/>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My Error: The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Please post your `web.xml`.what error do you get?

Comment: web.xml posted. The error im getting is The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Change value in @RequestMapping to "/login" and in `web.xml` set `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: @R.S That worked! Can you explain why that fixed it? Thanks!!

Comment: Dear, have a look to my blog:http://javalink2me.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-remove-any-suffix-extension-in.html

Comment: Your problem was so simple you configure your request url as *.htm but you called action="login"

Comment: @user3593826 It's because in `web.xml` you had set url pattern to handle requests/action which ends with `.htm` so `login` action will not work.So changing it to \ will handle all kind of requests like `.jsp`,`*.htm` or `login` etc.

Comment: Changing to 'login.htm' in `@RequestMapping` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the code is ok but try

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)

**"/login"**
when u hit the submit the form will be submitted by appending **"/"** in the url so it looks for **/login** in controller requesting ,mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the code is ok but try

Ur web.xml is having url pattern *.htm
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)

**"/login.htm"**
when u hit the submit the form will be submitted by appending **"/"** in the url so it looks for **/login.htm** in controller requesting ,mapping.

and in **dispatcher-servlet.xml** u no need to mention and beans like controller as you are using Annotation **@Controller**

Write this in the dispatcher-servlet.xml with spring bean urls on the top of **xml** and place jsp in **WEB-INF/jsp** folder

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Additional lookup : http://javalink2me.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-remove-any-suffix-extension-in.html

Answer (score 0):

right you have to add  
and you can use internalresourceViewResolver class to set prefix and suffix